# Angular + PersistenceJS and multiple async relationships

Tags: javascript, angularjs, persistence

Hi and many thanks for your help, 
I am facing a little problem where I cannot find many examples or help on the web : the multiple loading of relationships in PersistenceJS in order to display them on the same Angular View.

To be more clear I have this kind of objects and relationships :

- Store 1<-->* Article 1<-->* Images

So I defined the relationships between the objects :

My **Store** object

```
entities.Store = persistence.define('Store', { ... });
//Relations
entities.Store.hasMany('articles', entities.Article, 'store');
```

My **Article** object

```
entities.Article = persistence.define('Article', { ... });
//Relations
entities.Article.hasMany('images', entities.Image, 'article');
```

My **Image** object

```
entities.Image = persistence.define('Image', { ... });
```

My Angular View is just a list of stores with their items and images, using ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="store in stores">
    <h1>{{store.name}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="article in store.articles">
        <h2>{{article.name}}</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="image in article.images">
            <img src="{{image.link}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller method calls the service to load everything from the database :

```
dataService.getStoresData().then(function(stores) {
    $scope.stores = stores;
});
```

And my service is doing the load and here is where I am stuck, I tried a lot of things and here is my last version :

```
getStoresData: function () {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var query = entities.Store.all();
    query.list(null, function (stores) {
        deffered.resolve(stores); //As soon as possible ?
        for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) { 
            //For each store, load the articles
            var storeData = stores[i];
            storeData.articles.list(null, function (articles) {
                storeData.articlesData = articles;
                for (var j = 0; j < storeData.articlesData.length; j++) {
                    //For each article, load the images
                    var articleData = storeData.articlesData[j];
                    articleData.images.list(null, function (images) {
                        articleData.imagesData = images;
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })
    return deffered.promise;
},
```

In my first version, the problem was that my relationships won't show because, first, they are not yet loaded and then they are not simple arrays but they are *QueryCollection*. 
Then I changed to have the service here above and I changed my view to reflect the change (store.articlesData and article.imagesData) but it is not yet working.

I did a codePen as simple as possible to reproduce the problem : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJdrPo. Hope it can help to make things more clear :)

Is there any way to make this working or I need to change my database structure ? 
Is there any way to load all the objects and their relationships more efficiently ?

Many thanks for your help,

Have a nice day,

*Gerfaut*